# SpriteKit/Metal memory leak with nothing happening

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, metal

I have a memory leak that I can't seem to trace. Instruments sees it, and reports it as jet_buffer_Metal, but I don't know what that is pointing me to specifically.

[image]

It happens regularly. I have tried everything. Removing all my nodes, removing physicsBodies, but it still seems to be there. I don't have anything in Update or any other of the game cycle methods. I can post all that code there, but really I only add two nodes, that can only move on touch. I don't touch the screen, and the memory leak is still there.

One of my nodes has a PhysicsBody of circleOfRadius, and I have heard there might be some leaks with those types before, but again, the leak is still there if I remove the node with that physicsBody.

Finally, I am getting this in my debug window:
`<SKMetalLayer: 0x14ce28da0>: calling -display has no effect.`

I have a hunch it is related, but can't find where it is coming from.

I am using an SKS file that is currently empty. The nodes are added in code for now.

Comment: Which Xcode do you use? Do you have showsPhysics = true in your view controller?

Comment: 7.3.1 and yes I do.

Comment: try to disable physics visual representation and see if problem persists (showsPhysics = false).

Comment: That was it. Turning off showPhysics fixed the leak. WTH. Do you know why?

Comment: Yeah, it is a known bug :)

Comment: Answer and I will give you the points. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Ah it is fine, don't worry about points. Glad to hear that problem is solved. Happy codding!

Comment: haha, yup that darn showPhysics bug stinks.  That is why I create a build schema that enables showphysics, this way when I need to test the physics, I run this specialized schema, when testing memory, I use a normal schema

Comment: How would you set `showsPhysics` to false if you have no sprite kit view? I'm using a sprite kit scene as input for a Scene Kit element and I'm getting a similar leak with metal

Comment: Check your view controller. It can be set there.