# CGImage related memory leak in SceneKit application

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, scenekit

I am writing a 3d game using Scene Kit. When I used Leaks profile in Instruments, I find leaks exist. For the first red cross icon, it says 51 new leaks. Also if you see further down the leak checks area, there are grayed out dashed icons which say no new leaks.

[image: CGImagePlus memory leak in Scene Kit]

To put it in context, I try to recreate a scene after one unit of play is completed and present that using `presentScene...`. That would crash after 4 or 5 units of play. I was getting memory warnings and hence I used the leaks profile.

I cannot figure out how to resolve this leak as I am only using the SceneKit API and not any Core Foundation API. It will be great if someone has a solution or can provide relevant pointers to fix this leak.

Comment: not sure if that can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950822/spritekit-metal-memory-leak-with-nothing-happening

Comment: @Guig The other post you pointed to recommends setting `showPhysics=false`, but I am not using that setting. Thanks for the pointer though.